# AJAX response not styled in JQuery mobile using Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have read in several posts that when you load an AJAX response into a DIV of a Jquery Mobile page, you will have to re-apply the style by triggering create (or pagecreate).

I have the below code:

```
<div data-role="content" id="handle-to-replace-content-div">
  <script>
    $('#handle-to-replace-content-div').load("/login.php");
    $('#theMainPage').trigger('create');
  </script>
</div>
```

Here, `#theMainPage` is the id of the page role `<div data-role="page" id="theMainPage">`.

The form returned in my AJAX response still does not get styled and shows up as plain vanilla HTML. What am I missing?

Comment: inside `login.php` add `<script>$('form').trigger('create');</script>`

Comment: That did the trick. omar, is this a new requirement to apply it on each UI element? I am refactoring an old jquery mobile app, and i see that they used trigger('create') only on the DIVs and I have seen it working then.

Comment: No, its not a new requirement. `.trigger('create')` and `.trigger('pagecreate')` have special usage. On active page, if you call `.trigger('create')` on a div, it enhances all elements / widgets within. `.trigger('pagecreate')` is used when you add / modify major parts of a page i.e. header, footer...etc

Comment: Understood. I called .trigger('create') on the parent DIV inside which my form is a subset of the ajax responses included within it. So not sure why to .trigger('create') the form in php. Also, when the same AJAX response is loaded from other section post the first page, it works without form's .trigger('create'), interestingly.

Comment: it depends how you load it. `.load()` is different than `.loadPage()` and `.changePage()` etc... all those use ajax

Comment: thanks Omar. I removed .load() and did a normal ajax call from all places and it works without form's .trigger('create') and just fine if I do it on the DIV.